# situar frame en el centro de la pantalla

Tags: java, java-swing

hola tengo un programa que muestra un frame con su panel y sus dos cajas de texto, en la pantalla. Pero me la muestra en la esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla y yo quiero mostrarla en el centro, y no encuentro el modo.Este es el codigo minimizado.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class ProgressBarSwingWorker {
          
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Datos");    
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField numeroHerederos = new JTextField();
    JTextField numeroBienes = new JTextField();
    JButton siguiente = new JButton("Siguiente");   
       
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressBarSwingWorker();
    }
    
    public ProgressBarSwingWorker() {       
        construyePanel();        
        construyeVentana();           
    }
    
    void construyePanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2 + 1, 1));
        panel.add(numeroHerederos);
        panel.add(numeroBienes);
        panel.add(siguiente);        
    }
        
    void construyeVentana() {        
        frame1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame1.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame1.add(panel);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: agrega en el metodo `construyeVentana()` `frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Comment: perfecto, me sirvio. Muchas gracias!